# template lambda sometimes doesn't compile

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I would like to implement a generic visitor pattern for my trie data structure. Below is the extracted minimal fragment which makes trouble for compilers:

```
#include <functional>

struct Node {
    size_t length;
};

template<typename N>
class C {
public:
  size_t longest = 0;
  std::function<void(const N )> f = [this](N node) {
    if(node->length > this->longest) this->longest = node->length;
  };
};

int main() {

  Node n;
  n.length = 5;
  C<Node*> c;
  c.f(&n);
}
```

It compiles with g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1), Ubuntu clang version 3.4-1ubuntu3 and with Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79). icc (ICC) 14.0.2 says:

```
try_lambda_T.cc(15): error: "this" cannot be used inside the body of this lambda
  if(node->length > this->longest) this->longest = node->length;
```

I found a similar post:
[Class with non-static lambda member can't use default template paramers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12668003/class-with-non-static-lambda-member-cant-use-default-template-paramers)
That story resulted in a bug report which was resolved in g++ 4.8.1:
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54764

However, g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) results in:

```
internal compiler error: in tsubst_copy, at cp/pt.c:12125
   std::function<void(const N )> f = [this](N node) {
                                        ^
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
```

What can I do with it to have it compiled newest g++ (and, hopefully, icc)?

Comment: Does icc complain if you use `longest` instead of `this->longest` within the body of the lambda? You don't have to say `this->`, capturing `this` means you have access to the class' data members. You've found a gcc bug (an internal compiler error is always a bug), you should report it.

Comment: I tested it, same internal error for `longest` instead of `this->longest`. `g++4.9` on `OS X`.

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug, however you could try capturing `longest` by reference instead of `this` instance as an interim workaround perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gcc-4.8.1 compiles the code if you don't use a non-static data member initializer to initialize `f`

```
template<typename N>
class C {
public:
  C()
  : f([this](N node) {
        if(node->length > longest) longest = node->length;
      })
  {}
  size_t longest = 0;
  std::function<void(const N )> f;
};
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/384cc3e67fe0a3a9)

It even works if you prefer referring to `longest` as `this->longest` within the body of the lambda.

Comment: Thanks! It even fixes the icc build!